# SQL Statement join where if one condition is not met, then do the other one

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Lets say I have two tables

NAME_TABLE

| ID1 | ID2 | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | JACK |
| B | 2 | CRAIG |
| C | 3 | RYAN |
| D | 4 | LARRY |

JOB_TABLE

| ID1 | ID2 | JOB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | ENGINEER |
| B | 1 | TEACHER |
| E | 3 | ANALYST |
| F | 4 | ARCHITECT |

I want to make a query that first checks compares the ID1 of each table, and join them where they match. If there is no match in ID1, then we compare the ID2s.

So the final table would look like this. Notice that if the ID1s match, we don't care about doing anything with the ID2. We only care about ID2 if there is no ID1 match:

FINAL_TABLE

| NAME | JOB |
| --- | --- |
| JACK | ENGNEER |
| CRAIG | TEACHER |
| RYAN | ANALYST |
| LARRY | ARCHITECT |

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `left join`s:

```
select nt.*,
       coalesce(jt1.job, jt2.job) as job
from name_table nt left join
     job_table jt1
     on nt.id1 = jt1.id1 left join
     job_table jt2
     on nt.id2 = jt2.id2 and jt1.id1 is null;
```